# Defining a method which takes a parameter in a map

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have a use case where I am creating multiple AWS resources, for example S3 buckets, SNS topics etc in a cloudformation stack. All of these are bare minimalistic resources i.e the S3 bucket would not have any objects in it.

I have a workflow set up where my code will pick up a random resourceType and then create the resource. Now, I am trying to build a generic class/method which would delete these created resources.

I store the resources as json fields which give me the details about the resourceType

```
{
  "AWSService": "S3",
  "AWSResourceType": "Bucket",
  "ResourceAttributes" : {
      "BucketName": "MyBucket"
  }
}
```

For the cleanup, I was thinking that I have a map with key as the AWSService and the value to be a runnable which would call the appropriate serviceType to delete the resource.

But, runnables cannot take in parameters, and therefore I cannot pass in the resourceName/Arn to be deleted so that the API knows which resource to delete.

Is there a way I can store this information as a map and still pass in parameters to the method being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand all of the implications of what you are doing without seeing some code, but I think this might get you going in the right direction.

You can implement the Runnable interface in a new generic class: http://leo.ugr.es/elvira/devel/Tutorial/Java/essential/threads/clock.html

So what you could do is create a generic class that implements the runnable interface, and has either a constructor that can take the variables you need, or getters/setters, etc.

Something along the lines of:

```
public class ResourceCleanup implements Runnable {
    private String arn;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do the cleanup with the arn
    }

    public ResourceCleanup(String arn) {
        this.arn = arn;
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Or you could pass in the map instead of the String, use Java Generics, etc. as necessary. Hope this helps!